# Maintain cardinality in hash map when removing objects from arraylist

Tags: java, algorithm, methods, hash, hashmap

I wrote this method which extracts the max elem from a queue that contains Node objects. The main problem is that when I do the remove, the indexes of the elements decrease by 1, so in the hashmap I lost the correlation between Node-Position (my hashmap is: `HashMap <Node<T,E>, Integer> hmap`)

```
public Node extractMax() throws PriorityQueueException {
    if (getSize() == 0) throw new PriorityQueueException("Cannot read from an empty queue");
    Node max = getRoot();
    queue.remove(0);
    hmap.remove(max);
    heapify(0);
    return max;
  }
```

How can I solve it with a complexity <= O(n)?

Comment: Re-design your code, so you don't have a map with queue index positions.

Comment: Further to @Andreas comment: why do you need the list and the map? Wouldn't just the map suffice?

Comment: you can store in the queue objects that represent the node and it's position, what is your end game? I think that by providing the big picture you will get much suitable answers

Comment: A TreeMap will keep insertion order if you can't redesign it.

Comment: I need the hashmap because I must know the index of an object in the arraylist in O(1).

Comment: The short answer is that you can't do this with the standard Java PriorityQueue class. Your best bet is to implement your own or use something already written. The basic idea is to write the insert and remove methods so that whenever an item's index changes, you change the corresponding value in the map.